# ajax function not working after adding async and await keywords

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

Below mentioned code is working fine.

```
$.ajax({
   url: '?module=abc&action=xyz',
   //Ajax events
   beforeSend: function (e) {
     //
   },
   success: function (e) {
       const URL1 = '?module=mno&action=pqr';
        fetch(URL1);
   },
   error: function (e) {
     alert('error ' + e.message);
   },
   // Form data
   data: formData,
   type: 'POST',
   //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
});
```

But if I add `async` and `await` it doesn't work and also doesn't give any error in console. Like below code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '?module=abc&action=xyz',
   //Ajax events
   beforeSend: function (e) {
     //
   },
   success: async function (e) {
       const URL1 = '?module=mno&action=pqr';
        const RES = await fetch(URL1);
        let output = await RES.json();
   },
   error: function (e) {
     alert('error ' + e.message);
   },
   // Form data
   data: formData,
   type: 'POST',
   //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
});
```

Don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? You assign the resolver value of the promise returned by `fetch(URL1)` to `RES`, but then don't do anything with it. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Utkanos I have added `let output = await RES.json();` statement in the question. The thing is the code doesn't cross `const RES` statement.

Comment: How are you ascertaining that fact?

Comment: @Utkanos the query which I am fetching `fetch(URL1)` is not executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it, I just removed the code from inside `success` and add a new `function` and it worked.

```
$.ajax({
   url: '?module=abc&action=xyz',
   //Ajax events
   beforeSend: function (e) {
     //
   },
   success: async function (e) {
       //I added the below 'runquery()' function.
       runquery();
   },
   error: function (e) {
     alert('error ' + e.message);
   },
   // Form data
   data: formData,
   type: 'POST',
   //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
});
```

And then added a new `function`

```
async function runquery() {   
    const URL1 = '?module=mno&action=pqr';
    const RES = await fetch(URL1);
    let output = await RES.json();
 }
```